# Is writing a discriminated union to MongoDB possible?

Tags: mongodb, f#

Running the following piece of code:

```
type Test = 
  | L of int
  | M of string
  | N of bool

let client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017")
let _db = client.GetDatabase("TestDB")
let collection = _db.GetCollection<Test>("TestLog")

collection.InsertOne(L 22)
```

I get the following inserted in to my collection:

```
_id: ObjectID('58d054f79a91e00c8379ab82')
_t: "L"
```

So it looks like Mongo's .NET driver doesn't know what to do with discriminated unions. I have seen some libraries out there but they're very old and I want to check that there is nothing built in to the framework first. Another thing I tried was using Newtonsoft's JSON serializer like this:

```
let Json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(L 22)
let doc = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(Json)
```

Which gets everything in to the database, but they are all there with a string type instead of the types they should be (int, in this case).

Comment: maybe you should have a look into Chiron (https://xyncro.tech/chiron/). Its a JSON serializer specifically for F#

Comment: [FSharplu](https://github.com/Microsoft/fsharplu) as well. And it would be great if you could report back on your experience with either of those and mongodb.

Answer (score 1):

The [NamelessInteractive.FSharp](https://github.com/NamelessInteractive/NamelessInteractive.FSharp) serialization library deals with this very effectively. It works (and preserves type) very nicely with discriminated unions, record types, discriminated unions embedded in record types, etc.